# How to "catch all other values" FOR a column in a SQL PIVOT?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a SQL query where I'm calculating the number of players for a game based on `UserType` (only `1` counts as an actual player for the purposes of my calculation), and listing this info out for all games on a certain date:

```
SELECT
    gm.[Id]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN mbr.[UserType] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NbrPlayers
FROM
    dbo.[Game] gm
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[GameMembership] mbr ON gm.[Id] = mbr.[GameId]
WHERE
    CAST(gm.[DateCreated] AS DATE) = CAST('2023-04-30' AS DATE)
GROUP BY
    gm.[Id]
```

This gives the result, for my sample data:

```
Id                                      NbrPlayers
==================================================
FFA8C1D6-CEB6-4823-B436-18F0417EEBD0    2
E14B2558-F8B4-4660-967C-2EBC452BE881    0
208B46F8-B39D-4BC8-A907-57A07CD0A380    1
76275D64-AFD9-425C-8BD5-9FA770C24AA5    1
EA092967-680B-4EA6-A137-CD9834C51323    2
6C346BA1-1D3D-410A-A1A3-CF0B2F840C0E    1
EC68A93E-996F-4D4E-B443-DE63BD9B9F59    1
06C9A62D-9790-4080-8863-F7F2D0432F67    1
428D6C3F-57AF-4F6C-AE7F-F8C5D10AA6A5    2
DF027EE0-FAA3-4DA2-844A-F94AB6D56C2C    1
C82E60DF-7193-4099-B273-FE497B3002E5    1
```

However, what I then want to do is turn this into a single row of output, with columns for each distinct `NbrPlayers` value.  As I know that I have `0`, `1`, and `2` in this output, I can do this with `PIVOT` like so:

```
SELECT
    [0] AS [0pGames], [1] AS [1pGames], [2] AS [2pGames]
FROM (
    SELECT
        gm.[Id]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN mbr.[UserType] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NbrPlayers
    FROM
        dbo.[Game] gm
        LEFT JOIN dbo.[GameMembership] mbr ON gm.[Id] = mbr.[GameId]
    WHERE
        CAST(gm.[DateCreated] AS DATE) = CAST('2023-04-30' AS DATE)
    GROUP BY
        gm.[Id]
) x
PIVOT (
    COUNT([Id])
    FOR [NbrPlayers] IN ([0], [1], [2])
) pvt
```

Which results in:

```
0pGames    1pGames    2pGames
=============================
1          7          3
```

This problem is, what happens when I get other `NbrPlayers` values, and I don't necessarily know in advance what they might be?  What's more, I actually don't want a separate column for each one of those other values; I want one column that sums up "everything else".  Say I had a couple of entries for `NbrPlayers` being `3`, and a couple where `NbrPlayers` was `7`.  I'd want an output like:

```
0pGames    1pGames    2pGames    AllOtherGames
==============================================
1          7          3          4
```

As far as I can tell, `PIVOT` doesn't have this "catch-all" functionality that can be specified in the `FOR` clause, so how can I achieve this?

Comment: This is, in my opinion, much easier with conditional aggregation, rather than the (restrictive) `PIVOT` operator.

Comment: Would be good if you could post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the pivot manually, in other words use conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT
  [0pGames] = COUNT(CASE WHEN NbrPlayers = 0 THEN 1 END),
  [1pGames] = COUNT(CASE WHEN NbrPlayers = 1 THEN 1 END),
  [2pGames] = COUNT(CASE WHEN NbrPlayers = 2 THEN 1 END),
  AllOtherGames = COUNT(CASE WHEN NbrPlayers NOT IN (0, 1, 2) THEN 1 END)
FROM (
    SELECT
      gm.Id,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN mbr.UserType = 1 THEN 1 END) AS NbrPlayers
    FROM dbo.Game gm
    LEFT JOIN dbo.GameMembership mbr ON gm.Id = mbr.GameId
    WHERE gm.DateCreated >= '20230430'
      AND gm.DateCreated < '20230501' 
    GROUP BY
      gm.Id
) gm;
```

Note the use of a date range, rather than casting to date which is inefficient.

Also, your main query seems questionable. You are using a left-join, but then filtering in the `COUNT`. You could equally filter inside the left-join, then just count the number of matches.

```sql
SELECT
  [0pGames] = COUNT(CASE WHEN NbrPlayers = 0 THEN 1 END),
  [1pGames] = COUNT(CASE WHEN NbrPlayers = 1 THEN 1 END),
  [2pGames] = COUNT(CASE WHEN NbrPlayers = 2 THEN 1 END),
  AllOtherGames = COUNT(CASE WHEN NbrPlayers NOT IN (0, 1, 2) THEN 1 END)
FROM (
    SELECT
      gm.Id,
      COUNT(mbr.GameId) AS NbrPlayers
    FROM dbo.Game gm
    LEFT JOIN dbo.GameMembership mbr ON gm.Id = mbr.GameId
        AND mbr.UserType = 1
    WHERE gm.DateCreated >= '20230430'
      AND gm.DateCreated < '20230501' 
    GROUP BY
      gm.Id
) gm;
```

Comment: I'm casting to date because the actual query I need to build `JOIN`s onto a table which has a `DateTimeOffset` column, which needs to be made into discrete days.  As far as I know that requires casting it to `DATE` to eliminate the time portion?

Comment: Also, do you mean "filtering in the `SUM`"?

Comment: No you can use a range filter like I have done. Eg `JOIN Dates d ON gm.DateTime >= d.BeginningOfDay AND gm.DateTime < d.BeginningOfNextDay` or similar. No I meant `COUNT` because `SUM(CASE ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` is the same as `COUNT(CASE ... THEN 1 END)`. You can't sum a random value, but you can count it (as `COUNT` ignores nulls)

Comment: I don't have a `Dates d`, I derive the rows of output based on the discrete days that are represented by the input rows' DateTimeOffsets.

Comment: Not sure what you mean (do you mean grouping by date?), but the point is that you can still filter the `WHERE` using a date range. So you can hit an index by filtering by date range, then group up afterwards. I can't help you on that as it wasn't in your post, I suggest you make a new question for it.

Comment: Yes, grouping by date like `GROUP BY CAST([DateCreated] AS DATE)`.